# Conflict in R package: methods and package:base

Tags: r, conflict

I am trying to learn R programming basics.But I have bumped into a problem while  trying to use already installed packages 'nycflights13'. When I run library(flights), it gives error.

> library(flights)
>   Error in library(flights) : there is no package called ‘flights’

When I run conflicts(detail=TRUE), it displays below message:

> conflicts(detail=TRUE)
>   $`package:methods`
>   [1] "body<-"    "kronecker"

$`package:base`
[1] "body<-"    "kronecker"

I tried googling a lot.But could not find a solution. Can you please tell me what I am supposed to do to get rid of the conflict so that I can use the 'flights' data frame for practice?

Comment: Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to load the `flights` dataset from the `nycflights13` package?

```
library(nycflights13)
data(flights)
```

Comment: Yes, that's true.see the output below

Comment: library(nycflights13)
1: data(flights)
Invalid input, please try again